# Exact procedure to add a new node in cassandra 3.0

Tags: cassandra

Initially i had a 2-node cassandra cluster, in which both the nodes were seed nodes, Now i want to add an new non-seed node. The cluster has replication factor 2 and uses simple strategy. I have tried lot of solutions mentioned with no success. Can someone please outline the exact steps required.